# Opening an oracle database crashes the service

Tags: service, database-administration, oracle10g

I am experiencing a weird issue with Oracle where the service started fine after a crash. The database mount went fine as well. However, when I issue `alter database open;` command, the database does not open, gives a generic cannot connect to the database error & crashes the service.

Oracle support has not seen this issue before so it's pretty scary. The fact that there are no logs that give any leads as to what could be causing this is also scary.

I was wondering if good folks over at Server Fault had seen something like this or have some insights on things that I could try.

It's Oracle 10g running on Windows Server 2003.

Thanks,

Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ones like this, you need to go back to troubleshooting 101.

What's changed?

Are all of the disks readable / available?

Are there any OS errors in the OS error logs?

There is almost always something somewhere that will give you a hint at where the issue is, it is just hiding.

Comment: @KevinK - Thanks for your response. The problem was compounded by the fact that there were no logs that actually hinted towards a proper action plan. Weird thing is that we updated Oracle to the latest version of 10g and the database opened fine. Not the kind of solution that makes me feel better but good thing is data is back online. Thanks!